# Data source credentials greyed out in Power BI server online

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-datasource

I am using Excel spreadsheet as data source for my power BI reports save them in share point on premises. Initially , I was able to refresh my power BI reports online and schedule refreshes. But now I tried changing the name of the spread sheet and saved it again in Share point and tried to refresh it, the scheduled refresh is still disabled and am unable to add my data source credentials. I tried checking data source settings with Power BI desktop and no luck. Can any one help me resolving this issue? I am not sure where am I missing the data source connections.

I tried the possible options below  but didn't help
https://monocroft.com/how-to-fix-data-source-credentials-greyed-out-issues-in-power-bi/

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you able to refresh locally in power bi desktop?

Comment: Yes @zach . I am able to refresh locally in Power BI desktop.

Comment: Have you published since refreshing locally?

Comment: Yes Zach. It’s still the same. When I refresh in power BI desktop it works fine. But the data source credentials is still greyed out in power BI online.

Answer (score 0):

If you changed the name of the file on sharepoint, you will need to adjust the query in Power BI Desktop to reflect the new name. After you publish again using the new name in Power Query, you should be able to put in credentials in Power BI Service to automatically refresh.